# Netflix SSL certificate shows up when trying to visit https://www.google.com

Tags: ssl, certificate, https

I'm on a hotel Wi-Fi network where occasionally the following message shows up in Chrome when trying to visit any Google sites over HTTPS:

[image]

The SSL certificate reported when this happens is

[image]

This error doesn't happen all the time, but still pops up regularly. It only happens for Google websites; all other websites work over SSL, and all non-SSL websites work as well.

What could be causing it? If it's a misconfiguration of the proxy server or router connecting the network to the internet, why does it only happen for Google, and why is a Netflix certificate showing up?

Answer (score 5):

Could be a poisoned local DNS server... I'd try setting your computer to use google's public DNS to see if you get better results (8.8.8.8).

Better yet, be suspect of this network and stay off of it without a vpn

Answer (score 1):

This means that your browser could not check the identity of the certificate or issuer of it. The issuer name may be correct, but it's serial may not be.

Your network may proxy and open your SSL connection. Check it the issuer and CA serial are the same your computer trusts.

Here are the correct serials:

- CA

  - Common Name: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
  - Serial: `00 9B 7E 06 49 A3 3E 62 B9 D5 EE 90 48 71 29 EF 57`
- Issuer

  - Common Name: VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
  - Serial: `2C FE B6 09 0E E2 AD E2 E9 FC 22 37 24 F1 B6 BF`